# How to retrieve data column by column in dart from list of maps?

Tags: database, list, sqlite, dart, flutter

I need to retrieve values from 2 columns from SQLite database and I'm using helper query to to it.

I tried by indexing the values.

`print("In the login List : "+ lg[0].toString());`

But I'm getting

`In the login List : {email: xxxx@gmail.com, password: xxxx}`

```
  Future<bool> loginUser(String username, String password) async {
    bool isSuccess;
    Database db = await this.database;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> lg = await db.query(regTable,
        columns: [colEmail, colPassword],
        where: "$colEmail = ? AND $colPassword = ?",
        whereArgs: [username, password]);
    if (lg.length > 0) {
      print("In the login List : "+ lg[0].toString());
      isSuccess = true;
    } else {
      isSuccess = false;
    }
    return isSuccess;
  }
```

I need to be able to retrieve email and password separately.
Like,
`print(Email : lg(email));`

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out.

```
      lg.forEach((f){
        print(f["password"]);
      });
```

This gets me what I want. But if you have some suggestions please feel free.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `List` of `Map`s. It looks like you want to generate a list of specific key values from that list. The `List` method `map` is great for this sort of problem. For example:

```
final emails = lg.map((item) => item["email"]), 
  passwords = lg.map((item) => item["password"]);
```

(These are actually plain `Iterable`s; if you want `List`s, just add `.toList()` at the end.)